# GitBucketの.gitignoreが効かない

Tags: git

クローズ環境でGitBucketを立ち上げ、リポジトリの通常利用はすでに出来る状態です。

GitHubの別リポジトリで使っていた汎用的な.gitignoreを流用して配置したのですが、なぜか効いてくれません。

https://www.gitignore.io/
改めてこちらで作り直した.gitignoreも試したのですが効きません。

「gitbucket gitignore 効かない」などで探した記事では、Git側のキャッシュに残っているという情報も多々ありましたが、それらを試しても効果がなく、書き方やファイルの問題でなくGitBucket自体の設定で反映されていないような印象があります。

rootアカウントで見てもそれらしい設定は無いため、もしご存知の方がいましたら教えて頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: .gitignoreは手元で不要なファイルを登録しないようにするものなので、GitBucketかどうかはあまり関係ないように思いましたが、どうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
確かにローカルでgit操作をする時点でgitignoreが効いていない状態でした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

不要なファイル全てに対して

```
git rm --cached <不要なファイル>
```

など(ディレクトリやワイルドカード指定も可能です)とした後で

```
git commit -m "不要な理由など"
```

することで、まずは管理したくないファイルをリポジトリから取り除きます。

その後、`.gitignore`が最新の状態であることを確認し、もしリポジトリに最新のものがコミットされていなければ

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "コミットメッセージ"
```

とすると良いのではないかと思います。

---

尚、`git`の仕組み上、この処理で取り除かれたファイルはコミット履歴を辿れば中身を知ることは可能です。もし完全に削除したい場合は、もう少し手続きが必要となります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご回答いただいた方法での削除も試していたのですが、どうにもgitignoreファイル自体に問題があるようでした。

Comment: .gitignore自体がGitに正しく認識されていなかったため再度ファイルを作り直し試したところ正常動作するようになりましたためクローズとさせて頂きます。
別リポジトリで利用できていた.gitignoreのコピーでは何らかの異常が起きていたようです。